# XmlStarlet xml to csv output as 'NaNNaNNaN'

Tags: csv, xmlstarlet

I wrote a a query `xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m badges/row -v "concat(@row, ',')" 
-n Badges.xml` and the output is repeated as:

```
NaNNaNNaN...
```

for what is likely the amount of rows in the Badges.xml file. I am following this tut: https://www.joyofdata.de/blog/transforming-xml-document-into-csv-using-xmlstarlet/ to transform the xml formatted data to CSV. Anyone understand what is going on here?

[image]

Edit, here are some sample rows of the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<badges>
 <row Id="1" UserId="1" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2016-08-02T15:56:07.133" 
  Class="3" TagBased="False" />
 <row Id="2" UserId="8" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2016-08-02T15:56:07.133" 
  Class="3" TagBased="False" />
 <row Id="3" UserId="9" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2016-08-02T15:56:07.133" 
  Class="3" TagBased="False" />
 <row Id="4" UserId="19" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2016-08-
  02T15:56:07.133" Class="3" TagBased="False" />
 <row Id="5" UserId="27" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2016-08-
  02T15:56:07.133" Class="3" TagBased="False" />
```

Comment: You probably need to provide your input data too. It looks like it's converting something to a number that shouldn't be.

Comment: No I did not understand what is going on, please proofread and edit question. By the way NaN is often printed if you try to print a number that is not a number (Not a Number). This can happen if you divide a number by 0, or depending on the language try to do arithmetic with something that is not a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XPATH `@` points to an attribute name.
To generate csv records based on attributes values of each `<row>` node use the following approach:

```
xmlstarlet sel -T -t -m 'badges/row' -v \
'concat(@Id, ",", @UserId, ",", @Name, ",", translate(@Date," ",""), 
",", @Class, ",", @TagBased)' -n Badges.xml
```

The output:

```
1,1,Autobiographer,2016-08-02T15:56:07.133,3,False
2,8,Autobiographer,2016-08-02T15:56:07.133,3,False
3,9,Autobiographer,2016-08-02T15:56:07.133,3,False
4,19,Autobiographer,2016-08-02T15:56:07.133,3,False
5,27,Autobiographer,2016-08-02T15:56:07.133,3,False
```

Comment: Really great explanation of how @ works in XPath. Did not understand it before this post.